# sending attachment integrated in the app using kotlin

Tags: kotlin, email, email-attachments

I want to attach a file to sending an email. The mail is working fine without the attachment. It cannot find the *generalConditions.pdf* file that I want to attach. This file is (integrated) part of the application such as *generalConditions.pdf* for example. I don't know how to drop that file in the structure of the app to make it integrated to the app.

```
...
val fileName = "generalConditions.pdf"
val file = File(this.filesDir,fileName)
if (!file.exists()) {
    return
}

val subject = "Our GeneralConditions"
val uri = Uri.fromFile(file)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
val addressTo = emailTo.split(",".toRegex()).toTypedArray()
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addressTo)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)

intent.type = "mail/rfc822"
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email using:"))
...
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You  may need to [include the *content URI*](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file#RespondToRequest) for the file, instead of the `file://` URI. You will also need to [grant read permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file#GrantPermissions) for that file.

Read more here:

https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/share-file

Comment: Thanks, It's a bit complicated for me, I'm on kotlin since may 21. Could I ask you if you have a running example ?

Comment: I think I was not clear enough in my question, I'm sorry for that. I know how to send something from external storage. What I don't know is how to drag the ready-made pdf file into it so that it is integrated into the application?